# codec can't decode byte 0x81

Tags: python, codec

I have this simple bit of code:

```
file = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
```

I simply want to get the number of lines in the file. However I keep getting this error. I'm thinking of just skipping Python and doing it in C# ;-)

Can anyone help? I added 'utf-8' after searching for the error and read it should fix it. The file is just a simple text file, not an image. Albeit a large file. It's actually a CSV string, but I just want to get an idea of the number of lines before I start processing it.

Many thanks.

```
in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4344: 
character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You have two open statements in your two lines. The first decodes with utf-8. The second does not. Perhaps you could use the more modern "with ... open(...encoding='utf-8') .. as f:" construction?

Comment: ah, sorry, I never realised my code. I changed it from a loop to what you see now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be an encoding problem.
In your example code, you are opening the file twice, and the second doesn't include the encoding.
Try the following code:

```
file = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
num_lines = sum(1 for line in file)
```

Or (more recent) :

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in file)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I changed my code and didn't realise.

btw, I thought Python 3.x changed to unicode by default?

Comment: @Neil: The default encoding depends on the OS. See [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 76: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843725/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81-in-position-76-invalid).