# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 76: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I want to create a program that decodes wifi passwords.
I am not finished yet, but the program should print the names of all wifis. But there is this error and
I don't know how to fix it.

```
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n")
wifis = [line.split(":")(1)[1:-1] for line in data if "All User Profile" in line]
print (data)
```

Error:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"]).decode("utf-8").split()
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 76: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netsh` is a hint that you are using a Windows system. The console applications often use cp850 encoding for West European languages. So you could try :

```
data = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"]).decode("cp850").split("\n")
```

Or to be safe you can use an encoding able to accept any input byte like latin1 but it seldom returns the expected characters on Windows. But **NEVER** use `utf-8` when the input is not utf-8 encoded.