# having issues with String.find() in Python

Tags: python, html

I have been working on a basic web crawler/scraper for a school project. For testing purposes, the webpage is being read from a local .txt file that itself is just a copy of the html code of the page.

my code is essentially the following:

```
page = ''
with io.open('example.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        page += line
file.close()
search_term_1 = 'thing_t3_'             # what I am actually searching for
search_term_2 = '<!DOCTYPE html'        # example
search_term_3 = '<!DOCTYPE html>'       # example

page.find(search_term_1)                # this returns -1
page.find(search_term_2)                # also returns -1
page.find(search_term_3)                # returns 0, as it is the first thing in the document

print(type(page))                       # prints <class 'str'>
print(type(search_term_1))              # prints <class 'str'>
```

With a few other tests, I have found that the .find() method is only working when my search term is an entire line of the file. Removing line breaks and other escaped characters did not solve the issue.

Something worth noting is that I had earlier encountered an issue similar to [this decoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217956/python-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81) when reading in my file. While explicitly specifying utf-8 for the encoding seems to solve the problem, I can't be sure it is not the source of my issue.

Comment: That's impossible.  If search_term_3 returned 0, then search_term_2 must also return 0.

Comment: Do remember that your `page` variable will include newlines.  You might as well just have said `page = file.read()`.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect: output, not comments.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your file reading with a test case that elicits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a methods other than the built in .find(), there are two solutions I would recommend:

Solution 1:

Iterating through each line in your text file and comparing it to what you are trying to find.

For example:

```
for line in page:
     if search_term_1 in line.strip():
          break # do something
```

The other method which I prefer is using the `re` module (regex).
This allows you to run many operations for pattern matching.

You can use the .search() method built into the `re` module in this scenario.

Example code:

```
if re.search(search_term_1, page): # returns not None if pattern found anywhere on the page
     pass #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things to note about your code:

1. You have an excess declaration of `page = ''` where instead you could instantiate the `page = io.open('example.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')`.
2. Also, I think the only way for `search_term_2` and `search_term_3` to have differing results is if there is something incorrect in the method of tokenizing the input.

Answer (score 0):

I had oversimplified my code when posting it. I was also reading in by search terms from a file, and there was a \n character at the end of each search term. This was why I was only able to match the page file when searching for a whole line.