# Python: Remove digits and decimals from text file

Tags: python

i wrote this code to remove digits and dots from a text file

```
import fileinput


for line in fileinput.input("/content/drive/MyDrive/011186973309203002021041922243182.txt", inplace=True):
    
    #remove digits
    result = ''.join(i for i in line if not i.isdigit())
    #remove . 
    result = result.replace(".","")
    print(result)
```

but im not getting any results why is that ? i cant see the issue. it is literally printing nothing like its empty what can i do ?

this is an example for the text file im running

[text sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6llX.png)

i get these error the first time i run the code

1-

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
> position 45-49: character maps to
>
> RuntimeError: input() already active

Comment: Assuming there's no exception (when opening the file) maybe it's empty. Try adding *print(line)* inside the *for* loop

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text file you are using?

Comment: no line is printed :\ . the text file is not empty i tried creating multiple new ones to test it but still

Comment: @KunalShah done, posted

Comment: Now that you've shown the error it's clear that you need to specify an appropriate encoding when opening the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `inplace=True` from your function call. According to the fileinput [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)

> "if the keyword argument inplace=True is passed to fileinput.input()
> or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file
> and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the
> same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced
> silently). This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its
> input file in place"

So printing will not work, as everything is being piped to your input file.

Also depending on your use case, fileinput may not be the most appropriate module to use. Again, referring to the fileinput documentation:

> This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a
> loop over standard input or a list of files. If you just want to read
> or write one file see open().

Comment: it worked i love u

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this more transparent solution instead.

- Open the input file for reading
- Open the output file for writing
- Only *keep* characters which are not digits or a decimal, and write them to the output file

**Note:**
The `encoding` parameter *might* need to be changed if an 'invalid byte' type error is thrown - to match the encoding of your source file.

---

```
import string

digits = string.digits + '.'

with open('./leena.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fi, open('./leena_out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fo:
    for line in fi:
        fo.write(''.join(i for i in line if i not in digits))
```

---

The issue with the previous code, is that the text file is being edited *in place*, without returning the results, as you might be expecting.

This example, is more transparent, in that you can see (and have control over) what is being read, transformed, and written to the output file.

Comment: im getting -> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 137: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: This indicates a character which cannot be decoded in position 137 of the input file. Check the input file for 'odd looking' characters. Given a pure ASCII text file, this will work just fine.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217956/codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81). (I'll update to enforce the encoding. However, you'll need to change the encoding if your file is encoded differently.)

Comment: This error may be caused because you are not specifying an encoding when opening the file, try adding, encoding='utf-8'.

Comment: @KunalShah - Yep, got it. Already updated. Thanks.